# GraphQL Generics Unexpected Value Type Error

Tags: graphql

I can't figure out how to make the GraphQL types happy with my Generics plan. I am trying to have a response wrapper for all my query and mutation definitions.

Everything was working fine with my query definition using PaginationType and my service returning the Pagination model and all was good. I added the ResponseType wrapper and now I get the conflict.

> Expected value of type "ABC.GraphQL.Framework.DTO.ResponseType`1[ABC.GraphQL.Framework.Types.Object.PaginationType]\" for \"ResponseType\" but got: ABC.GraphQL.Framework.DTO.Response`1[ABC.GraphQL.Framework.DTO.Pagination].",

```
FieldAsync<ResponseType<PaginationType>>(
   "PaginationSearch",
   "Returns paginated groups for specified search terms",
   arguments: new QueryArguments(...),
   resolve: async context => {
          return await Service.GetPagination(...);
          }
);
```

```
public class PaginationType : ObjectGraphType<Pagination>
{
   public PaginationType()
   {
      Field(x => x.totalRecords, nullable: true).Description("Total Records");
       ....
   }
}
```

```
public class ResponseType<T> : ObjectGraphType<Response<T>>
{
   public ResponseType()
   {
      Name = "ResponseType";
      Field(x => x.success, nullable: true).Description("Operation Success");
      Field(x => x.message, nullable: true).Description("Operation Message");
      Field(x => x.response, nullable: true, typeof(T)).Description("Operation Response");
    }        
}
```

Of course the plain backing models

```
public class Pagination
{
   public int totalRecords { get; set; }
  .....
}

public class Response<T>
{
   public bool success { get; set; }
   public string message { get; set; }
   public T response { get; set; }
}
```

Now my service class returns the plain objects and this has been working to this point so not sure why adding the Response wrapper is now breaking it.

```
public async Task<Response<Pagination>> GetPagination(...)
{...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged into the GraphQL library and found it is by design. So I begun digging into to why and found this:

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/2279